# how to fix expecting anything but ''\n''; got it anyway

Tags: groovy

I have the following line in my code

```
def genList = (args[]?.size() >=4)?args[3]: "
```

when I run my whole code I get the following error

expecting anything but ''\n''; got it anyway at line: 9, column: 113

here I am adding the whole code so you can see what I am doing

```
def copyAndReplaceText(source, dest, targetText, replaceText){
    dest.write(source.text.replaceAll(targetText, replaceText))
}
def dire = new File(args[0])
def genList = (args[]?.size() >=4)?args[3]: " // check here if argument 4 is provided, and generate output if so
def outputList = ""
dire.eachFile { 
    if (it.isFile()) {
        println it.canonicalPath
        // TODO 1: copy source file to *.bak file
        copy = { File src,File dest-> 

            def input = src.newDataInputStream()
            def output = dest.newDataOutputStream()

            output << input 

            input.close()
            output.close()
        }

        //File srcFile  = new File(args[0])
        //File destFile = new File(args[1])

        //File srcFile  = new File('/geretd/resume.txt')
        //File destFile = new File('/geretd/resumebak.txt')
        File srcFile = it
        File destFile = newFile(srcFile + '~')
        copy(srcFile,destFile)

        // search and replace to temporary file named xxxx~, old text with new text. TODO 2: modify copyAndReplaceText to take 4 parameters.
        if( copyAndReplaceText(it, it+"~",   args[1], args[2]) ) {
   // TODO 3: remove old file (it)
               it.delete()
   // TODO 4: rename temporary file (it+"~") to (it)

   // If file was modified and parameter 4 was provided, add modified file name (it) to list
   if (genList != null) { 
     // add modified name to list
     outputList += it + "\n\r"
   }
  }
    }
}
// TODO 5: if outputList is not empty (""), generate to required file (args[3])
if (outputList != ""){
    def outPut = new File(genList)
    outPut.write(outputList)
 }
```

Thank you

Answer (score 10):

Just close your double quotes

```
def genList = (args?.size() >=4)?args[3]: ""
```

Comment: I did that and now i am getting this error, (sorry if I ask too much, i just have two days working on this language which is new to me)

`java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 0

 at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.dgmimpl.arrays.ObjectArrayGetAtMetaMethod.invoke(ObjectArrayGetAtMetaMethod.java:38)

 at groovy.lang.MetaMethod.doMethodInvoke(MetaMethod.java:233)`

Comment: Try dropping the `[]` from `args[]?.size()`

Answer (score 2):

The specific OP question was already answered, but for those who came across similar error messages in Groovy, like:

- `expecting anything but '\n'; got it anyway`
- `expecting '"', found '\n'`

It could be caused due to multi-line GString ${content} in the script, which [should be quoted with triple quotes](https://groovy-lang.org/syntax.html#_triple_single_quoted_string) (single or double):

`''' ${content} '''` or `""" ${content} """`

Answer (score 0):

Why do you have a single `"` at the end of this line: `def genList = (args[]?.size() >=4)?args[3]: "`?

You need to make it: `def genList = (args[]?.size() >=4)?args[3]: ""`

Comment: I commented the `"` and now I am getting the following:


unexpected token: def at line: 10, column: 1

which will be related to 

`def outputList = ""`

Comment: No you don't. @geretd has just commented out the double quote, so the code makes less sense than before. Instead of commenting out the `"` just close it with another,  ie: `""`. Even the github code highlighting above shows where the error is

Comment: well I did as you guys have suggested and I am still getting the error, I don't know what is wrong... any more ideas, about what can i do to fix it?

Comment: Oh my, that was a silly mistake on my part. Yes, just add another `"` and make it `def genList = (args[]?.size() >=4)?args[3]: ""`!

Comment: @lapint yeah that is what I did 

here is how it looks like know

def genList = (args[]?.size() >=4)?args[3]: "" 
def outputList = ""

Answer (score -2):

You need to add a `;` token at the end of `def outputList = ""`

Also get rid of the `"` at the end of `def genList = (args[]?.size() >=4)?args[3]: "`

Comment: Thank you I did as you said but I am still getting an exception:

`unexpected token: def at line: 10, column: 1`

any idea? thank you very much

Comment: @dmahapatro can you tell me how it should look like?

this is how it looks like now:

`def genList = (args[]?.size() >=4)?args[3]: ""`

and I am getting this error:

`java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 0

 at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.dgmimpl.arrays.ObjectArrayGetAtMetaMethod.invoke(ObjectArrayGetAtMetaMethod.java:38)

 at groovy.lang.MetaMethod.doMethodInvoke(MetaMethod.java:233)`

Comment: @geretd Concisely, what are you actually trying to achieve from this script?